# Checking empty text boxes which convert strings to integers using "int.Parse" method in C#

Tags: c#

How do I check the empty check boxes which convert strings to integers using "int.Parse" in C#?

If I try to pass blank text boxes, visual studio gives me this error - "Input string was not in a correct format."

[image]

I already read some questions on stackoverflow which address the same issue, but I know that various people use various methods to do the same task. So I would like to know them as well. Please start with the simplest way you know first.

Answer (score 9):

```
int multiplyBy;
if(int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out multiplyBy)) {
   //success
} else {
   //string was not in correct format
}
```

The `int.TryParse(string s, out int result)` method trys to parse the string, but throws no exception if the format is wrong, it returns a bool indicating if the format was valid. The `out int` result parameter is the int wich should get the value.

Answer (score 4):

Use Int32.TryParse to verify that the value in the text box is a valid integer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

You can check if the textbox has a value with:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text)
```

Comment: I'm talking about text boxes with "int.Parse method". "IsNullOrEmpty" doesn't work on those text boxes.

Comment: IsNullOrEmpty works on string values, not on controls.  Textbox.Text is a string value and works as expected when passed as a parameter. As I said, use Int32.TryParse.  Read the link that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly parsing string representation into integer, check whether it is able to convert in integer. .NET has TryParse method of integer which tries to convert the string representation into int , and returns the bool value indicates whether the conversion succeeded. And if succeeded, stores the parsed value in second parameter of TryParse function which is of out type.

Note: TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails. It simply returns false indicates that conversion is got failed.

Ref : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you want it in single line of code

*vb.net*
`int i =  If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text), 0, Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text))`

*c#*

`int i =  (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text)) ?? 0: Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text)`

Comment: What happens if the value in the TextBox cannot be parsed to an int?

Comment: You can use int32.TryParse() method instead.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just catch the exception

```
try
{
      int multiplyBy = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
} catch(Exception){}
```

You can also catch(FormateException) if you like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not only is this the wrong approach, it's not even the correct way if you *had* to use exceptions - you are trapping a general exception which could be masking other problems. At a minimum you should at least he catching FormatException.

Comment: You should not use exceptions for logic flow.  They are for 'exceptional' events.